# Microsoft SQL version compatibility

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I need to install  Microsoft SQL express edition   for basic learning stuff, I have Windows 7  home Premium SP1 edition  and visual web developer 2008 installed.

When I Google it shows me  more than 1 options against each download of SQL SERVER   can someone guide me which  version of SQL server is suitable for my OS?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All are. That simple. BUt tell me a reason not to use the most modern one, please.

Comment: i did  install 2012 but  after installation it simply said its not compatible to your machine and when i tried to remove  it and install other one then i came to know that its registery files are never removed but  i will have to  reverse some registery keys  and that was really tough for me , thats y i asked it

Comment: Well, given that the requirements for Server 2012 - if you care to  read them  at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx - include WIndows 7 Home Premium this is not a compatibility issue but "hey, you did something wrong".

Comment: fixed all the issues :)